# Generate list of evenly distributed numbers from zero to limit with specific sum and count

Tags: python

I want to write a Python function to generate a list of positive numbers that are evenly distributed from zero to a max called `limit`. The sum of the list should equal a value `total_sum` and the list should consist of `count` number of items.

For example:

```
func(limit=50, total_sum=150, count=6)
# [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

func(limit=200, total_sum=500, count=5)
# [0, 50, 100, 150, 200]
```

How can I write this function? Is it even possible? After writing this, I think it's only possible in rare cases, like the ones above.

Comment: You are correct that it's not possible with free choice of all three values. For a given pair of `count` and `limit`, there is only one possible value of `total_sum`. (Specifically, `total_sum == count * limit / 2`)

Comment: question: do you have to start at 0 or can you start at any number between 0 and limit?  i.e. is (10,20,30) a solution to func(limit=50, total_sum=60,count=3)?

Answer (score 0):

```
def wanted (limit,total_sum,count):
     interval=limit/(count-1) #here we used count-1 to know between elements 
     result=[]
     for i in range(count):
         result.append(round(interval * i,1)) #generates evenly spaced nums

     scaling = total_sum/sum(result) # to know the ratio we should multiply
     
     result=[round(j*scaling,1) for j in result]
  
     return result
```

print(wanted(limit,total_sum,count)